# Change color of an object in Lab that does not share the same channel

Tags: photoshop, lab-colorspace

Lab tutorials show how to change a red car into a green one. That is convenient, because red and green share the same channel.

But, if I would need to change a red car to a Yellow or blue one, how would you go about that? Would you use blend if?

EDIT:

for example, in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhfRynutmQM at 2 minutes from beginning, he changes the car from red to green by Inverting the red/green channel. But if he would like to have a blue car, the Blue is on channel b, not channel a as red. How would he do that?

EDIT2:

As a sample, how would you make the flowers from pink to blue and the leafs from green to red on this ugly photo? going from pink to blue is not that difficult, but I find it quite challenging to change the green into red...

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the general case of shifting from [R1,G1,B1] to [R2,G2,B2], or about matching intensity while s;hifting hue?

Comment: I am asking (as the title says) about Lab color space. NOT Rgb.

Comment: And I'm asking just what kind of resultant shift you want to produce..

Comment: ok sorry, misunderstanding there.. updating the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say I want to change this image, "[Still, by Sara Dorweiler via Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/?photo=x2Tmfd1-SgA)" to make the leaf blue. Let's start with an info point.

[image]

So we have -12, 20. For blue it should be something fairly close to 0 and then a negative value.

A simple curve can handle that.

A Channel curve:

[image]

B Channel curve:

[image]

Which you can see brought the Info Point to 0, -60. You can of course tweak those to your taste and the exact blue you want.

Obviously now there's a cast so depending on the image you may have to do at least a rough mask but Blend-if can handle this one with breeze. And with a more complex one that's why you do a rough mask and then Blend-if.

[image]

Comment: Have tried your technique with the above posted image, but I do not seem to be able to make it without using layermasks.. Could you please make one of your tutorials? Thanks!